# Two apps share same universal link

Tags: ios, firebase, deep-linking

I have two apps under same firebase project, those share the same deep link

How are links handled by the OS if more than one App can use the same universal link? How do I choose the app that is going to be opened to handle certain pages?

for example, both apps share same universal link https://xxx.app.goo.gl
how will it be identified to open user or manager app?

Comment: Pretend you had full control over how iOS controls universal links. How would you design it to handle two apps that can handle the same link?

Comment: I'd allow for URL query components to be parsed and routed accordingly.

Comment: @BallpointBen on Android the user get's to choose the app if there are multiple apps that support a given domain/deep-link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html), this is dependent on the ordering of your AASA file.

> The order of the dictionaries in the array determines the order the system follows when looking for a match, so you can specify an app to handle a particular part of your website.

The app that is listed first in the AASA file will take precedence. You can check that by looking at the AASA endpoint: https://xxx.app.goo.gl/apple-app-site-association

You can also specify certain paths to be handled separately, but if both apps share the same paths then the one listed first in the AASA will open.

Comment: Thank you for making things more clear, So is it more appropriate to separate them as two firebase projects to have different universal  link ?

Comment: If the apps do not share any of the same content, I definitely would separate them. Hope that helps!